# The [touch] tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[touch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touch) has 24 questions and no wiki. Some of these questions are obviously talking about [touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchpad) (175 questions) or [touchscreen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchscreen) (52 questions), but some are talking about a device with *touch* in the name or even the **[touch command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utouch.htm)**

Suggestion:
There is <s>no</s> consensus among these 24 questions and they should be retagged <s>and burninated</s>. Additionally, the [touch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touch) should be edited to reflect the touch command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I retagged them to use [touchscreen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchscreen) and [touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchpad).

Whether [touch-gestures](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touch-gestures) is necessary, I don't know. We could just use [gestures](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gestures), it seems to be used for that.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the touch command is the topic that seems to be what this tag should be, to me. Everything else should be able to be under [touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchpad) [touchscreen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchscreen) or a possible new [touch-gestures](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touch-gestures). There's no other way of talking about the touch command.

Comment: I can get on board with this, but it should be a synonym for [tag:touch-command]

Comment: @Raystafarian It needn't be a synonym, really. If the `[touch]` tag wiki explains what it's about, that's generally fine. Let's split it up in to touchpads, touchscreens, what have you. I like `[touch-gestures]` as well, but depends on how much use we have for that.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/324108/software-to-extend-touch-gestures-on-windows-7-tablet-pc would be an example of touch-gestures, where there's no other tag at the moment

Comment: This is a great example where a good tag wiki (excerpt) can prevent confusion.

Comment: … given that people actually read it :P

Comment: I updated the wiki for touch to reflect it is the `touch` command (once approved). The re-tagging can begin if it is deemed the appropriate action. The burninating should be off the table per this discussion.